# Global variable in Drools rule

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

Is there any way I can get back the Integer value updated in Drools rule. I am passing the string in my rule. I can see my rule running but I am not getting the updated global variable's value. Here is my Drools rule file :

```
import com.MessageType;

global java.lang.Integer delayInSeconds;

rule "Delay for Update"
when 
String(this == MessageType.UPDATE.getType())
then
System.out.println("Running delay rule.....");
delayInSeconds = 10;
update(delayInSeconds); // This gives me runtime error. If I remove it I dont get error but dont get updated value.
end
```

I have also tried this : 
kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("delayInSeconds" , 10); but no luck :(

I know I can pass this variable by setting in POJO. So just wanted to confirm if there is any way by we can get updated value using global Integer. Please suggest.

Answer (score 8):

Global variables are a different species. You can read them, you can use them almost (!) like plain old variables, but:

Any update of a global variable must be done via the API method `KieRuntime.setGlobal()`.

In your rule, you could use

```
drools.setGlobal( delayInSeconds, Integer.valueOf(10) );
```

You cannot use update with a global - it is not a fact. Also, rules will not react to a change of a global. Use a fact if you need this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just used this
kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("delay , 10");
I was accessing the variable directly. I had to use kSession.getGlobal("delay ").

Comment: how to make global into a fact? What is the different?

Answer (score 6):

For me this worked

```
drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal(String, Object);
```

Eg.

`drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("delayInSeconds", Integer.valueOf(10));`

Comment: Or, more precisely, when using the above in the RHS of a rule: the String is a string representation of your global variable, while Object is it's new value.  <br/>    E.g.:   <br/>    `drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("loopCounter", Integer.valueOf(loopCounter + 1));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use.

```
then
   System.out.println("Running delay rule.....");  
   delayInSeconds = "whatever calculations";
   drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("delayInSeconds", delayInSeconds);
end
```